# Usage of Rindler coordinates in studying Unruh Effect

Tags: special-relativity, reference-frames, acceleration, coordinate-systems, unruh-effect

When studying the Unruh Effect, Rindler coordinates are being used for the observer with constant acceleration. I am confused as to why Rindler coordinates are used as I do not see the motivation for doing so. Is there an intuitive explanation to neatly explain why Rindler coordinates are used when considering observers with constant acceleration? Incidentally, by constant acceleration do we mean constant proper acceleration?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, we mean constant proper acceleration.

In Rindler coordinates an observer with constant "location" coordinate has a constant proper acceleration. That's why Rindler coordinates are used.

Comment: Why is it that we cannot use Minkowksi coordinates even though the hyperbolic trajectory can be described in Minkowsi coordinates? I am not sure when to use Minkowski and Rindler coordinates since I guess one can also say that an observer with constant acceleration is moving in Minkowski space.

Comment: @Thomas we can use any coordinates we want, so we choose the most convenient. In this case that's the Rindler coordinates.

Comment: Since we are interested in what an accelerating observer sees, it is necessary to study the situation in instantaneous rest frames of the observer. Rindler coordinates are then natural to use since they follow the accelerating observer. But one can do without them. [Alsing & Milonni](https://arxiv.org/pdf/quant-ph/0401170.pdf) don't use Rindler coordinates.